# Passing final vars to a MouseListener method and return a result

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I'm struggling with this code, I want to click on one of the cells of the grid, made by `JPanel` objects, and in that cell make appear a label with the index of that cell. I made a method to add final vars and return the JPanel with that label. It's not working. How can I do this?

```
 public MyTest01(int width, int length) { //constructor

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length)); //set layout
    JPanel temp = null;
    JLabel l;

    for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            temp = new JPanel();
            temp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
            temp=doStuff(temp,x,y);
            frame.add(temp);
        }
    }

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
    frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
}

public static JPanel doStuff( final JPanel temp,final int x, final int y) {

MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
       JLabel  l = new JLabel("("+x+" - "+y+")");
     temp.add(l);

    }
};
return temp;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: In "doStuff" you create a MouseListener, but you don't actually attach it to anything. Something like temp.addMouseListener(mouseListener) will get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: It would be better to make those panels be a `JButton` instead, and add an `ActionListener` to each.  Not only will the button react to both mouse or keyboard, but buttons have inbuilt methodology to show focus.

Answer (score 1):

1. You never add the listener to the `JPanel`.
2. You need to `revalidate` and `repaint` the `JPanel` after adding a component (`JLabel`);

   ```
   MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
           JLabel l = new JLabel("(" + x + " - " + y + ")");
           temp.add(l);
           temp.revalidate();;             <-------- revalidate
           temp.repaint();                 <-------- repaint
       }
   };
   temp.addMouseListener(mouseListener);   <-------- add listener
   return temp;
   ```

---

Here is the working code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MyTest {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public MyTest(int width, int length) { //constructor

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width, length)); //set layout
        JPanel temp = null;
        JLabel l;

        for (int y = 0; y < length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                temp = new JPanel();
                temp.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 1));
                temp = doStuff(temp, x, y);
                frame.add(temp);
            }
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
        frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new MyTest(3, 3);
            }
        });
    }

    public static JPanel doStuff(final JPanel temp, final int x, final int y) {

        MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                JLabel l = new JLabel("(" + x + " - " + y + ")");
                temp.add(l);
                temp.revalidate();;
                temp.repaint();
            }
        };
        temp.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: That solution worked, thank you very much. But now i need add an ActionListener to all of the board, this is for a game of life, i just need to run, here is what i have so far. https://codeo.me/3EP Can you give me a pointer..